# Converting the factor data to POSIXct format

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

The data is in factor format "2018-01-02T20:40:40.000Z" and I want it to be in POSIXct format "2018-01-02 20:40:40". How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `?strptime` to know more about date-time formats

```
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2018-01-02 20:40:40 GMT"
```

---

With `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(x)
#[1] "2018-01-02 20:40:40 UTC"
```

---

Or with `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anytime(x)
#[1] "2018-01-02 20:40:40 UTC"
```

**data**

```
x <- factor("2018-01-02T20:40:40.000Z")
```